# Mysql with low memory on development environment

Tags: mysql, memory, virtual-machines

How to set mysql to run on very low memory? (preferably under 100MB and max 250MB)

Currently it's running for about 400mb. I can't turn off the innodb because production using innodb. Is there any configuration that can reduce everything to minimum? (barely alive is ok, even if it's only can handle one request per second)

I've searched around and almost all telling me it will reduce performance. Currently I don't care for performance because there is another server for that. This is only for local environment on top of VM.

Comment: http://www.tocker.ca/2014/03/10/configuring-mysql-to-use-minimal-memory.html

Comment: @thanasisk I've tried that, no luck :( only able to reduce from 25% ram usage to 20% ram usage of 2gb.